# Why are C++ features unable to be used in extern "C" prototypes but able to be used in the implementation to link in C?

Tags: c++, c, linker, abi, linkage

Functions in extern "C" are interpreted in C manners, e.g. no name mangling. However, why do C++ features, such as STL, `std::string`, smart pointer and so on, can be used in the function definition but cannot be used in the function declaration (**to link with other C code**)?

For example, I want to use `std::vector` in extern "C". As far as I know, if it's used in the implementation, the .obj file will have such instructions to jump to the ctor, etc; if it's used in the prototypes, it should do so too, and there seems to be no difference between them.

Besides, there is a related question for currently I'm studying ABI. What's the relationship between so-called ABI and language linkage in C++? How does ABI influence linking with extern "C" C++ code in C?

Comment: *Functions in extern "C" are interpreted in C manners, e.g. name mangling.* Huh?  Functions in C and `extern "C"` functions in C++ **do not** undergo name mangling.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I've changed my wording. Sorry for the ambiguity in my poor English :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are C++ features unable to be used in extern "C" prototypes but able to be used in the implementation to link in C?

Because the C compiler doesn't understand C++ specific code.

The implementation of the `extern "C"` function that uses C++ classes is compiled with a C++ compiler.

The C compiler only sees the function declaration, which can **not** contain C++ specific things, like `std::vector`s.

header.h - seen by both C and C++ compilers

```c
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int foo(const char*);          // works in both C and C++
// int bar(std::vector<int>&); // a C compiler can't compile this

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

impl.cpp - never seen by the C compiler, only the C++ compiler

```cpp
#include "header.h"

int foo(const char* something) {
    std::vector<int> bar;
    // use bar and do stuff
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I mean, the function prototypes have been changed into symbols and there is no real `std::vector` in the .obj file. What it implies is just operations on registers and stack, etc., to convey parameters. So when a C compiler tries to link that .obj file with C .obj files, how can it know "I don't recognize `std::vector`"?

Comment: @o_oTurtle _"have been changed into symbols and there is no real std::vector in the .obj file"_ - If you put `int bar(std::vector<int>&);` in the header file, the C compiler reading the header file needs to be able to understand it - which it doesn't. If you only use the header file from C++ code - fine, but then, why `extern "C"` link it? You can't use it from C code anyway.

Comment: @o_oTurtle - The C compiler never sees the .obj file with C++ code.  That is the job of the linker. And the C++ compiler produces code that the linker can handle.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That makes sense, I get it.

Comment: If you  want to pass `vector` as argument then you have to pass that as `void*`. And you need some C++ function that creates the `vector` and passes it as `void*` to the C code because C code can't create it's own `vector`s.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Indeed. I often hide C++ types in `typedef struct { void* data; } sometype_t;` -like structs and use them in the C API. When such a struct eventually reaches a function compiled with a C++ compiler, the pointer is cast back to the proper type and dereferenced.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Dart FFI allows for C++-isms in the declarations. You're supposed to compile a shared library that Dart can then interface with, so the only reason they bother to `extern "C"` stuff is just to not mangle names.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Good suggestion hiding the `void*` in a struct so you still have type safety.  Alternatively you can keep the type abstract, the C code doesn't need to know that `int_vec_t` is a `std::vector<int>*`.

Comment: @sweenish Yes, if one protects the C compiler from C++-isms by processing the file with another tool/preprocessor/compiler, anything is possible.